# Dynamic Union Query with Primary Key

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a union query that is a dynamic reference to a group of tables covering varying types of items. I want to create a linked table (via query)that will have manual entry that will use the union query as a contributing reference list. Now of course without a primary key, the recordset will not be updateable. I would like the union query to remain a dynamic list of items but without having a primary key to link the secondary table, there is no chance of updating ie allowing data entry on the second table.

It works with static created table ie generated by the union but would be nice and clean and my OCD would be eased by simply keeping it live and I think parametric management is always better.

The union query is of course simple...cut can the primary key be allocated here? ProdID is unique across all tables. Currently Cat_Code and Item_Code are a composite primary key in supporting tables

```
SELECT DataSheet_Products_NBC.Cat_Family, DataSheet_Products_NBC.Cat_Code, DataSheet_Products_NBC.Cat_Name, DataSheet_Products_NBC.ProdID, DataSheet_Products_NBC.Item_Code, DataSheet_Products_NBC.Item_Desc, DataSheet_Products_NBC.Unit
FROM DataSheet_Products_NBC
UNION 
SELECT DataSheet_Estimating_Statistics.Cat_Family, DataSheet_Estimating_Statistics.Cat_Code, DataSheet_Estimating_Statistics.Cat_Name, DataSheet_Estimating_Statistics.ProdID, DataSheet_Estimating_Statistics.Item_Code, DataSheet_Estimating_Statistics.Item_Desc, DataSheet_Estimating_Statistics.Unit
FROM DataSheet_Estimating_Statistics
UNION SELECT  DataSheet_Products_Other.Cat_Family, DataSheet_Products_Other.Cat_Code, DataSheet_Products_Other.Cat_Name, DataSheet_Products_Other.ProdID, DataSheet_Products_Other.Item_Code, DataSheet_Products_Other.Item_Desc, DataSheet_Products_Other.Unit
FROM DataSheet_Products_Other;
```

I need to end up with a query, containing the union query, with primary key and a data table that can accept data ie be updateable.

[image: fDatasheet view]

[image: Design]

Comment: Including a UNION query in a query results in non-updatable dataset. Period.

Comment: Hmm. Ok. I would still like to know how to dynamically assign a key to a union query either way. Can alter table or some command create the key at creation of the union query? Since its a virtual object, I can think of how else it would be possible

Comment: Cannot assign a PK in UNION query. I don't understand why you want to. Can still use UNION in another query and join on the common ProdID fields. ProdID is FK in UNION and it would join to PK in other table. Can use the UNION as source for INSERT to another table or MAKE TABLE.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info...thats how I was using the union but when I looked deeper (in access) its main complaint for no update was that the linked table was not update able without PK join. I ended up just running INSERT and add columns to reset the table, works ok but now its static ie not linked dynamically as I make updates to the members of the union etc. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can't Insert a new row directly to UNION query
So You will show the UNION on a subform 
Then put Text controls below to enter the new row 
**Table Name**, Cat_Family, Cat_Code, Cat_Name, ProdID, Item_Code, Item_Desc, Unit
Add a button to Insert the new row 
Requery the subform to view it

Comment: Thanks Siyon. Not sure if I was clear: At no time would a user enter any of the Cat_family etc: they are read only dynamic list. What I  would like to do is have a user fill out Obj_GlobID, Storey etc which is a related table. The AC_BOQ_AddDel table is completely empty at the beginning.